# Django CKEDITOR set max size of an image

Tags: django, ckeditor

how can I set the max size that an image can have in django-ckeditor? Here is the model's code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    text = RichTextUploadingField(max_length=1050,null=True,blank=True)
```

I tried to use `CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE` but it didn't work. Also if I can't set the max size of an image is there any other way to resize the image?

Thanks.